# how to get the printer name mapped to LPT1 port using Java

Tags: networking, printing

I have a new requirement to store the printer name ( \server\printer) connected to LPT1 into database table once user is logged on to the application in order to keep the default Zebra printer used by each work cell.
Is there any way to get the printer name mapped to LPT1 port using Java. The printers are mapped in Windows start-up dos script with net use lpt1 \server\printer

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Never found a good way to do it in Java, but you could try parsing the cmd line output of the PrintingAdminScripts in sys32

> cscript %windir%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\Prnmngr.vbs -l

for windows7, the Prnmngr.vbs script is another level in...

> cscript %windir%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prnmngr.vbs -l